Can we limit till what level we can list aws objects from s3 bucket?
I am working with s3 bucket and have build up a hierarchy something like below.

s3://student-subject-bucket/event-processed/student-score/subject=math/student_id=001/year=2024/month=04/day=02/
s3://student-subject-bucket/event-processed/student-score/subject=math/student_id=002/year=2024/month=04/day=02/
s3://student-subject-bucket/event-processed/student-score/subject=math/student_id=003/year=2024/month=04/day=02/
s3://student-subject-bucket/event-processed/student-score/subject=science/student_id=001/year=2024/month=04/day=02/
s3://student-subject-bucket/event-processed/student-score/subject=science/student_id=002/year=2024/month=04/day=02/
s3://student-subject-bucket/event-processed/student-score/subject=science/student_id=003/year=2024/month=04/day=02/
s3://student-subject-bucket/event-processed/student-score/subject=arts/student_id=001/year=2024/month=04/day=02/
s3://student-subject-bucket/event-processed/student-score/subject=arts/student_id=002/year=2024/month=04/day=02/
s3://student-subject-bucket/event-processed/student-score/subject=arts/student_id=003/year=2024/month=04/day=02/

The partitions are based out of keys which are created at runtime as per the data being pushed. My ask is basically to get the distinct subjects from the path above and do some further processing of the files.
So basically I am looking to get a list in return which for the above should return
("math", "science", "art")
I am using the AWS client builder to get the data but the problem is it is looping through the whole path which is fine in shorter run but as data will increase this might become very heavy and time consuming process.
Below is the code snippet
              val s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION).build()
              val request = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName("student-subject-bucket")
                .withPrefix("event-processed/student-score")

              var result: ListObjectsV2Result = null
              val eventList = scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet[String]()

              while (result == null || result.isTruncated) {

                result = s3.listObjectsV2(request)
                request.setContinuationToken(result.getNextContinuationToken())
                result.getObjectSummaries.forEach {
                  obj => 
                      println(obj.getKey)
                    //*** my procesing code goes here **//
                }
              }

Any pointer or ideas by which I can achieve this will be great. Thanks in advance.

You could use the following
...
val prefix = "event-processed/student-score/subject="
val request = new ListObjectsV2Request()
  .withBucketName(bucketName)
  .withPrefix(prefix)
  .withDelimiter("/")

var result = s3.listObjectsV2(request)
val subjects = Set[String]()

result.getCommonPrefixes.forEach {
    commonPrefix =>
    val subject = commonPrefix.stripPrefix(prefix).stripSuffix("/")
    subjects += subject
}

This stops at the level of subjects without going deeper into the hierarchy
